# Nautilus won't change folder icons

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, icons, customization

[image]

Since I upgraded my system to from Ubuntu 18.04.2 to 18.04.3, Nautilus stopped responding to folder icons (replicate images used as icons in `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` or a similar location). Suddenly, it doesn't support any customized icon and all my folders icons are gone!

I have tried several ways to fix this issue but i didn't found a sufficient solution

All that I did:

1. Changing icons with the traditional way (GUI) , selecting the required folder then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>), clicking on the folder icon then browsing to the required `.png` file (new icon) ... and this doesn't do anything
2. Using

   ```
   sudo gio set -t 'string' folder_name 'metadata::custom-icon' 'file:///home/required_icon.png'
   ```

   ...and this one return the following message

   > gio: Setting attribute metadata::custom-icon not supported
3. I tried to remove Nautilus, then reinstalled it again, but nothing changes

Please, can anyone help me to fix this?
Really, I can't do the job without customized folder icons...

In the picture I opened the same folder with Dolphin in the left and Nautilus on the right, I want to set a custom icon for each folder in Nautilus as I did with Dolphin, but it doesn't work :-\

Comment: You upgraded from which version? What do you mean with "all my folder icons are gone"? No icons anymore or generic icons? Edit your question to make it as precise as possible.

Comment: from 18.04.2 to 18.04.3 , i mean they are broken they just appear like the default folder icon

Comment: How about using [`folder-color`](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/04/change-color-folder-icons-ubuntu-1804/)?

Comment: i have recently tried it , and it doesn't work too

Comment: Tried some icon theme like Papirus ? How did it respond ?

Comment: nothing , it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

To change the icon of a folder in 18.04.3, you'll have to right click on the folder, click properties, then click the icon in the properties dialog:

[image]

And select a custom icon

[image]

That's it.

[image]

Comment: i have told you that this method didn't work , since the last update that i have did in the few previous days , and any folder that has a customized icon before the update it just returned to the default icon after i updated

Comment: Hmm. If you go to terminal and run `nautilus`, when you try to change a folder icon in the new nautilus instance that opens, do you see any error messages being printed in the terminal?

Comment: scripter@scripter-root:~/my files/IGEE/3rd year/L05$ sudo nautilus .
[sudo] password for scripter: 
sys:1: PyGIWarning: Nautilus was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Nautilus', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
RuntimeError: object at 0x7f15602d4640 of type FolderColorMenu is not initialized

Comment: It appears `folder-color` may actually cause this bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/folder-color/+bug/1826587. If you have any nautilus extensions installed, try purging them.

Comment: Also if you have any gnome shell extensions installed, try disabling all of them to see if that mitigates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the answer anyone wants to hear, but I had the same issue under Ubuntu 20.04. I was getting errors when I launched Nautilus from terminal like:

- Unexpected plugin response. This probably indicates a bug in a Nautilus extension
- GLib-GObject-CRITICAL g_type_add_interface_dynamic: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE

Which led me to these bug reports:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/315618
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/315623

In the end, I wiped my drive and did a clean install of 22.04, which fixed the original issue. Now I'm able to update folder icons.